# npm install error "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator."

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I  just upgrade my node into version v6.11.3
and the npm version is 5.4.1

I am trying to do

```
npm install
```

or any npm install such as

```
npm install nodemon
```

and having this problem.

```
 npm WARN deprecated pug@0.1.0: Please update to the latest version of pug, at time of writing that is pug@2.0.0-alpha6
 npm WARN deprecated pug-loader@0.0.0: Please use pug-load for pug-loader@<=1.0.2.
 npm ERR! path C:\Users\project\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json
 npm ERR! code EPERM
 npm ERR! errno -4048
 npm ERR! syscall unlink
 npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\project\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json'
 npm ERR!     at Error (native)
 npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\project\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2\package.json'
 npm ERR!     at Error (native)
 npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\project\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\aws-sign2\\package.json\'\n    at Error (native)',

 npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
 npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
 npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
 npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\project\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\aws-sign2\\package.json' }
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     C:\Program\_logs\2017-09-07T21_55_47_482Z-debug.log
```

I have been googling and trying a lot of different methods such as

```
 npm cache clean
```

but having this problem

```
 npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify'
 instead.
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     C:\Program\_logs\2017-09-07T22_03_49_893Z-debug.log
```

I am not sure how can I fix this problem and able to run my nodemon instead of  nodemon bin/www

Comment: try to open cmd as admin and run the command

Comment: if on a unix system: `sudo npm install `

Answer (score 6):

Try using **--no-optional** while installing any package. That worked for me.
`npm install nodemon --no-optional`

Answer (score 2):

You may have run the original node installation as an administrator. So now the administrator owns the global `node_modules` directory.

On Windows

- Right click the `cmd` or `powershell` application
- Choose Open As Administrator
- Try running `npm install` inside that particular command window

On OSX or Linux, use `sudo`.

```
sudo npm install
```

Comment: I did what you described but still having the same problem. I am wondering if its because of fsevents

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem today. I then installed yarn

```
npm install -g yarn
```

and then ran

```
yarn install
```

This told me the following:

```
info fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
```

So yarn was able to handle that and it worked for me.

Comment: I think the problem is the npm version. I figured it out by revered back to the previous npm version which is 5.2.0, and it works again.